# Coin Flip HTML / Javascript | (Help)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried to make my code work with the example below but after multiple hours of trying I'm giving up... Could someone please help me put this all together so it will work fine?

```js
var result,userchoice;
function resetAll(){
    var resetHTML = '<div class="tail"><img src="coin_F.png" /></div><div class="head"><img src="coin_G.png" /></div>';
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.coinBox').fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $(this).html(resetHTML)
        }).fadeIn('slow',function(){
            $('#btnFlip').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    },2500);
}
// Checking User Input
$(document).on('change','#userChoice', function(){
    userchoice = $(this).val();
    if(userchoice == "") {
        $(this).parent('p').prepend("<span class='text text-danger'>Please select a coin side to play the game</span>")
        $('#btnFlip').attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        /**/
        $('#btnFlip').removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).siblings('span').empty();
    }
    return userchoice;
});
// Final result declaration
function finalResult(result,userchoice){
    var resFormat = '<h3>';
    resFormat += '<span class="text text-primary">You choose : <u>'+userchoice+'</u></span> |';
    resFormat += '<span class="text text-danger"> Result : <u>'+result+'</u></span>';
    resFormat += '</h3>';
    var winr = '<h2 class="text text-success" style="color: #49DF3E;">You Won!!</h2>';
    var losr = '<h2 class="text text-danger" style="color: #c34f4f;">You Lost...</h2>';
    if(result == userchoice){
        $('.coinBox').append(resFormat+winr)
    } else{
        $('.coinBox').append(resFormat+losr)
    }
}
// Button Click Actions
$(document).on('click','#btnFlip',function() {
    if($('#userChoice').val() == "") return;
    var flipr = $('.coinBox>div').addClass('flip');
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
        flipr.removeClass('flip');
        //result time
        if(number) {
            result = 'Global';
        //alert('Head = '+number);
            $('.coinBox').html('<img src="coin_G.png" /><h3 class="text-primary">Global</h3>');
            finalResult(result,userchoice);
            resetAll();
        } else {
            result = 'Fortune';
        //alert('Tail = '+number);
            $('.coinBox').html('<img src="coin_F.png" /><h3 class="text-primary">Fortune</h3>');
            finalResult(result,userchoice);
            resetAll();
        }
    },2000);
    return false;
});
```

```css
#wrapper 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
}

.btn
{
    width: 12%;
    background-color: #c34f4f;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.btn:hover
{
    background-color: #A64242;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #A64242;
}

.container
{
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h1
{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.head
{
    margin-top: -205px;
}

.flip img{animation: flipIt 0.5s linear infinite;}
.head img
{
    animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

@keyframes flipIt
{
    0%{width: 0px;
        height: 200px;}
    25%{width: 200px;
        height: 200px;}
    50%{width: 0px;
        height: 200px;}
    100%{width: 0px;
        height: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Coin Flip | <span>Global or Fortune</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <!--blank-->
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <!--coin-->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="coinBox">
                        <div class="tail">
                            <img src="coin_F.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="head">
                            <img src="coin_G.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--user form elements-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
                        <p>
                        <div class="form-control">
                          <button name="Global" id="userChoice">Global</button>
                          <button name="Fortune" id="userChoice">Fortune</button>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="btnFlip" disabled>Flip It</button>
                        </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use this example but couldn't get it to work: `https://jsfiddle.net/8jw1ogLd/`

Comment: seems to work for me, what's the problem/point?

Comment: Basically what I wanted to do is to create two buttons, by pressing one of them player would pick side for example Global or Fortune. I can't figure out how to do it so when the players presses the button it will actually pick a side without refreshing the site...

Comment: The problem is that you want when the user chooses side and the page displays "correct" or "incorrect", the user has to be forced to choose the side again? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8jw1ogLd/6/

The only change is this:

```
 $(this).addClass("disabled");
```

on 25-th line. Is this answer solves your problem?

Edit:

This is the fixed jsfiddle with your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/45t3th0n/34/

Comment: That's not mine code. This is an example that I want to use to combine with my code to create two buttons which by pressing them will pick the side of the coin and then by pressing "flip it" it will flip the coin and then give you results.

Comment: OK. Can you create working jsfiddle with your solution?

Comment: This is what I tried to do and I can't find the fix for errors https://jsfiddle.net/45t3th0n/28/

Comment: What did u do? I really want to know if it was massive error or just small one

Comment: Just a two little mistakes. If you have github account you can create repository with your version and I can made pull request - you can see the differences very easy.